# how to make gridview expand?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a GRIDVIEW where the profiles of users are displayed in each grid fetched from Firebase Database using FirebaseListAdapter where I have populated the grids from the database.

Now I want an expand-collapse functionality where each grid can be expanded to show a another view.

I have looked into the following repository which uses ArrayListAdapter instead of FirebaseListAdapter:

https://github.com/thewaychung/ExpandableGridView

But when I try to implement the same with FirebaseListAdapter , it throws all sorts of errors.

My code without the expand functionality:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gv;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    Button t;
    TextInputLayout parentInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button t = findViewById(R.id.payBtn);
        final ExpandableGridView grid = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        ExpandableGridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //SETUP FIREBASE
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Log.i("TEST", "TEST");
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        FirebaseListOptions<users> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<users>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.users)
                .setLifecycleOwner(MainActivity.this)
                .setQuery(query, users.class)
                .build();
        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView age = v.findViewById(R.id.age);
                TextView id = v.findViewById(R.id.id);
                ImageView image = v.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                TextView cont = v.findViewById(R.id.cont);
                users mt = (users) model;
                name.setText(" Name: "+mt.getName());
                age.setText(" Age: "+mt.getAge().toString());
                id.setText(" ID: "+mt.getId());
                count.setText(mt.getCount().toString());
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(mt.getImage()).into(image);
                Button d  = v.findViewById(R.id.d);
                parentInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.parentInfo);
                parentInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This is the parent information",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextactivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

my code when i added the expand functionality with reference to the github repo:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gv;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter1;
    Button t;
    TextInputLayout parentInfo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button t = findViewById(R.id.payBtn);
        final ExpandableGridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextactivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        String[] countryData = {"China", "USA", "UK", "Russia", "France", "Germany", "Japan", "Korea", "Canada"};
        final String[] stateData = {"State A", "State B", "State C", "State D"};
        //SETUP FIREBASE
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Log.i("TEST", "TEST");
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        FirebaseListOptions<martyrs> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<users>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.martyrs)
                .setLifecycleOwner(MainActivity.this)
                .setQuery(query, users.class)
                .build();
        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView age = v.findViewById(R.id.age);
                TextView id = v.findViewById(R.id.id);
                ImageView image = v.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                TextView cont = v.findViewById(R.id.cont);
                users mt = (users) model;
                name.setText(" Name: "+mt.getName());
                age.setText(" Age: "+mt.getAge().toString());
                id.setText(" ID: "+mt.getId());
                count.setText(mt.getContribution().toString());
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(mt.getImage()).into(image);
                Button d = v.findViewById(R.id.d);
                parentInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.parentInfo);
                parentInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This is the parent information",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Nextactivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.grid_item,R.id.grid_item,countryData);
        //gv.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                gv.expandGridViewAtView(view, new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.users,R.id.name,stateData)); {
                });
            }
        });
        gv.setOnExpandItemClickListener(new ExpandableGridView.OnExpandItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, Object clickPositionData) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),clickPositionData.toString()+"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
     

    }

       /* @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            adapter.startListening();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            adapter.stopListening();
        }*/
}
```

Please help

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: no the app doesnt crash , the expand functionality just doesnt work

Comment: Then what does it mean "throws all sorts of errors"?

Comment: i meant to say that when i use firebaselistadapter instead of arraylistadapter(which is implemented in the above github repository) it says FirebaseListAdapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated
so it doesnt compile

Comment: So you get an exception. Add it to your question.

Comment: sorry i should've framed the question better, i made the edits plz see

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: Error at :
 gv.expandGridViewAtView(view, new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.users,R.id.nameLayout,stateData));
Error:FirebaseListAdapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated